# linking the fields in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
Table_gnews|
+-------------------+
| gnewsid=>int      |                
| gnewsh=>varchar   | 
| gnewsd=>varchar   | 

Data:
gnewsh:test
gnewsd:leadstart.in/blog
```

PHP code below

```
<?php

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "gb";
$password = "123";
$dbname = "test_database";
$limitStart = $_POST['limitStart'];
$limitCount = 100;
if(isset($limitStart ) || !empty($limitStart)) {
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
$query = "SELECT * FROM gnews ORDER BY gnewsid limit $limitStart, $limitCount";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$res = array();
while($result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$res[$result1['gnewsid']] ='<h3>' . <a href="$result1["gnewsd"]" target="_blank">"$result1["gnewsh"]"</a> . '</h3>';
}
echo json_encode($res);
}
?>
```

**What I want:**
When I click "test" it will open "leadstart.in/blog" in a separate tab.
I tried in this way: But no result

```
$res[$result1['gnewsid']] ='<h3>' . <a href="$result1["gnewsd"]" target="_blank">"$result1["gnewsh"]"</a> . '</h3>';
```

**Where  is the fault?**
Any Help

Comment: But no result means? what is the output you got or any error?

Comment: $res[$result1['gnewsid']] ='<h3>' . <a href="$result1["gnewsd"]" target="_tab">"$result1["gnewsh"]"</a> . '</h3>';
 would you try that?

Comment: yes tried. But no output

Comment: I think you missed the single quote `'`

Comment: That looks very wrong, check the quotes

Comment: Where I put the single quote?

Comment: `$res[$result1['gnewsid']] ='<h3> <a href="'.$result1['gnewsd'].'" target="_tab">'.$result1['gnewsh'].'</a></h3>';`

Comment: Maybe you should learn the PHP basics first, try this: `$res[$result1['gnewsid']] ='<h3>' . '<a href="$result1["gnewsd"]" target="_blank">"$result1["gnewsh"]"</a>' . '</h3>';`

Comment: Also `$result1["gnewsd"]` is not working in that string if you write it like that.

Comment: nothing is coming

Comment: "nothing is coming" is not very helpful.. are you calling the php page directly in the browser or through AJAX on some other site? Also there should be some errors at least with your original code that was not valid PHP. When you use a proper IDE to develop your code you can also run it directly without any browser to better find errors.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) driver. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$res[$result1['gnewsid']] ='<h3> <a href="'.$result1['gnewsd'].'" target="_tab">'.$result1['gnewsh'].'</a></h3>';
```